# Ctrl+shift+v not pasting in any terminal after swithcing to ubuntu-desktop on kubuntu 17.10

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

I installed ubuntu desktop and ctrl+shift+v is not working in any terminal emulator I try. Ctrl+shft+c still works. If I try ctrl+shift+v the cursor blinks but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the menu Edit/Preferences and then the shortcuts tab, under Edit, does it still have "Paste" listed with Shift+Ctrl+V ?

Comment: Yes I even tried setting it again and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Does Ctrl-v and Ctrl-Shift-v work in any other program?  Libre Office Write supports both.  Some web pages like gmail support both.  I am sure there are others.  I am trying to see if this is a global problem or just specific to the terminal.

Comment: I just tried it and it's not working in Libre Office Writer. I have also tried Konsole and Guake terminal and it's not working in them either. When I do press Ctrl+shift+v the line cursor blinks. Ctrl+v, Ctrl+c and Ctrl+shift+c are working.

Comment: So it sounds global.  Go to Settings, Devices, Keyboards and look through there to see if ctrl-shift-v is defined or disabled.  It would be good if you found it there, but you could also just click reset (as long as you hadn't defined any keys that you wanted to save.)

Comment: There was a shortcut for ctrl and I removed it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I checked the gnome keyboard shortcuts and there was a shortcut for ctrl key. I removed it and it is working now.